# MobileFirst Development Server User Credentials

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

IBM MobileFirst Studio 6.3 installed on Eclipse Juno. Accessing the Operations Console for the deployed application:

1. Prompted to enter User + Password.   What are the default credentials.
2. How can I disable the need to enter credentials for the development server.

Also, if you can reference where in the 6.3 documentation this information is detailed.  I was not able to locate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login screen will appear in cases of session timeouts.

In the development environment the default username/password combination is admin/admin.
These values are hard-coded.

I could not find the documentation for this as well.
I've sent a note about it. If anything comes up I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank You.  That worked fine.  Appreciate your time and help.